# Not flying from residing country, will there be an issue?

Tags: air-travel, usa, hong-kong, singaporean-citizens

I am currently holding an expatriate pass in Malaysia. I would like to fly to Hong Kong for a few days, then continue my vacation to LA from Hong Kong. Will there be any issues since I am not flying from my residing country? 
I am a Singaporean.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why there should be an issue.

You are a Singaporean national and being a Malaysian Resident should not be an issue at all. [Singaporean nationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Singaporean_citizens) are allowed to travel visa free to Hong Kong for up to 90 days, which I believe is lesser than your intended period of stay.

From there, you are free to board a flight to Los Angeles (United States) wherein you are allowed for up to 90 days at a single go as a part of the [Visa Waiver Program (VWP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program).

**Make sure that you fill out the [ESTA(Electronic System for Travel Authorization)](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) beforehand and there will be no issues.**

Comment: wow! thank you so much for your kind advice!! i will apply for the ESTA before i fly! :)

Comment: @pastelover No issues! Have a safe trip! :)